# Omitir entrada si se presiona solo enter en java

Tags: java, string

necesito saber como omitir la asignación de un valor a una variable si se presiona enter, siendo la asignación por medio de un input, es decir, si tengo una variable String y voy a asignarle algo por consola como por ejemplo un nombre, entonces, si escribo el nombre y doy enter ej: "Juan Perez" quedaría guardado en el string, pero si no escribo nada y solo doy enter, no debería de guardar nada y seguir con el codigo

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingresar nombre:");
    String nombre = input.next();
    //Si se ingresa algo y se presiona enter en consola guardarlo en nombre,
    //Si se presiona enter pero no se escribió nada, seguir con el codigo
    //Sin haber guardado nada porque no se ingresó nada.
    System.out.println("Ingresar cedula:");
    int ced = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: Debes de poner tu codigo para poderte ayudar. de lo contrario será complicado poderte ayudar. Saludos.

Comment: Sería algo como lo que edité, no sé como explicarme bien, solo necesito saber como hacer que siga con el codigo, si no ingreso nada y solo doy enter, que siga con el codigo y si ingreso algo y doy enter que lo guarde en la variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ocupar otro metodo de la libreria Scanner llamada `nextLine()`

El `nextLine()` acepta toda una linea completa de String (como si ingresaras una oración), si ocupas el `nextLine()` Java guardará en **Enter** como un String vacío, algo como así:

```
String nombre = "";
```

Y no pasará nada y Java seguirá ejecutando el código siguiente, ahora, si quieres saber exactamente que el usuario presionó la tecla **Enter** podrías ocupar un método del objeto Scanner: `.isEmpty()`, que como dice el nombre, verifica que el String esté vacío, o en tu caso, que el usuario presionó solo `Enter`, me imagino algo así:

```
String nombre = input.nextLine();
if(input.isEmpty()){
      System.out.println("Presionó Enter");
}
//Aquí seguiría tu demás código
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!, me compliqué mucho con eso, te agradezco mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar `input.nextLine();` en lugar de solamente `input.next();`

Comment: Una breve explicación del porqué no estaría mal para quien no sabe la diferencia.